# Should the title be CGCC and not just code golf?

Tags: discussion

When you go to our web page it says "code golf" at the top. This is true on my android cell phone at least. Should it instead spell out CGCC?  Everyone I have spoken to about this website was surprised it isn't just code golf. Perhaps changing the title they see would help with that.

Comment: The mobile version is being deprecated in favour of responsive design on the desktop version, so I doubt this will be fixed

Comment: @pxeger do you mean what you see in Chrome from a phone or using a specialist SE app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compare the mobile version of the site (using Android):

[image]

With the desktop version of the site on mobile:

[image]

As you can see, it is only the mobile version which has the short name. Also, there's [plans to depreciate the mobile version](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367609/deprecating-our-mobile-views)

Comment: Understood. Maybe that can be fixed?

Comment: @Anush I'd personally recommend just using the desktop version of the site by default. It's much nicer than the mobile version.

Comment: @Anush SE are slowly removing support for any way of using the site on mobile aside from the responsive desktop site. That means that the apps are dead, and the mobile version is being killed. I very much doubt they'll even bother to make this change when the entire mobile version will be non-existent in a year or so

Comment: When we talk about the mobile version, I just mean what you see on a mobile when using chrome, not anything to do with an app.

Comment: @Anush When you go to any Stack Exchange site on a mobile web browser (Chrome, Safari, etc.) it takes you to the "mobile site" by default (the top image in this answer). If you scroll down to the bottom of the page, you'll see in the footer a link saying "full site". Click this, and it'll show the second view shown here

Comment: @Dudecoinheringaahing thanks. So is it ccgc or cgcc?

Comment: @Anush CGCC - Code Golf and Coding Challenges

Comment: Thank you very much